# FTP router to FTPS for secure connection using TSL/SSL explicit in Apache Camel in Java

Tags: java, ssl, ftp, apache-camel, ftps

I have following existing ftp configuration and I want it to make as ftps configuration

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("com.fileprocessor");

    from("ftp://" + ftpServer + "/" + ftpDir + "?username=" + ftpUser + "&password=" + ftpPass
            + "&passiveMode=true&delete=true&delay=10000")
            .to("file:" + localDir);
    from("file:" + localDir + "?move=" + localDirPassed + "&moveFailed=" + localDirError)
            .unmarshal(bindy)
            .process(dwsProcessor);
}
```

so what are the changes do you think I need to make in this configure()
note :configure() method is from RouteBuilder class

Comment: ftp:// to ftps:// is the only thing I need to change ?

Comment: from method comes from org.apache.camel.builder and class is RouteBuilder

Comment: currently , for time being its working but I am not sure its fully secure or not so m waiting for testing team to be confirm and I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Apache Camel documentation for FTP/SFTP/FTPS Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html#_uri_format) shows, syntax for FTP and FTPS is identical, except that you replace `ftp://` with `ftps://`:

```
ftp://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options] 
ftps://[username@]hostname[:port]/directoryname[?options]
```

---

Explicit mode is default in Camel:

> `isImplicit` ... FTPS only: Sets the security mode(implicit/explicit). **Default is explicit** (`false`).